# Difference of communication between @Directive vs @component Angular 2.0

Tags: javascript, angular

What is  the difference between a component and directive in angular2 .Both have a set of html template attached to it. And a set of controller or function which handles the functionality.

What are the use cases of each in a application ?
In a component communication between 2 components is possible .Can same be done in directives. If so whats the difference really ?
I what cases should I use each of them....